# batch files use of variables with % or excalm sign

Tags: batch-file, variables

One line with `echo tezenden is true eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`
 is not executed although the variable `%tezenden%` is set to `true`.

I tried with **`"`**, **`%`** and **`!`**.

```
echo OFF
set tezenden=false
rem zoek de 2de extensie (dus nt de .lnk) in recent map
for %%a in ("%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.lnk") do for %%b in ("%%~na") do ( 
    echo %%a - is %%~xb
    if "%%~xb" == ".txt" (set tezenden=true
                echo variable is set sssssssssssssssssssssssss
    )           
    rem if "%%~xb" == ".pdf" (set tezenden=true)
    rem other conditions here (simulates OR)
    rem evaluate tezenden
    if "!tezenden!"=="true" (echo tezenden is true eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
        rem hier verzenden en dan deleten

    )   
)
rem if %tezenden%==true (echo tezenden is true)   %var% ok since outside block functions OK

pause
```

Any idea?

Comment: Considering that this is not your first question related to the same task, can you please explain what the task is, because it is not clear. You seem to be trying to make some determinations depending upon the file extensions of the targets of the `.lnk` files found in `Recent`. What exactly are those determinations? I don't mean what is this code supposed to do, I want to know what the over all task is.

Comment: I want to select files on their extension eg txt OR pdf OR odt, so I used a variable called "tezenden" in order to be able to select on those multiple extensions (instead of a non existing OR function in the IF) and then do some actions (send those files via mail with blat or mailalert) .

Comment: You really should read what a windows `.lnk` file is, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: What is your target Operating System?

Comment: you just forgot `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Comment: Thanks Stefan !!!!, this solved my problem. (It was on Windows 10, and I think I know what a shortcut is, LotPings)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example for you which uses [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) with it's `Like` operator, *which can be relatively slow*, but should properly parse the shortcut targets and output the existing targets whose extensions are `.odt`, `.pdf` and `.txt`.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where^
 "Extension='lnk' And Name Like '%AppData:\=\\%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\%%'"^
 Get Target /Format:"MOF" 2^>Nul')Do For %%B In (odt pdf txt
)Do If /I "%%~xA"==".%%B" If Exist "%%A" Echo(%%A
Pause
```

The code curently just `Echo`es the files, *(at the end of line `5`)*, you would obviously change that `Echo(%%A` as required. The last line `Pause` is included just so that you can read the output.

Comment: Nice Compo. Valuble alternative indeed!!

Comment: Even ifyou don't implement the code I've provided, it is important to note that you should still be making a check similarly, i.e. that the target file exists before performing any action on it. The `Recent` location does not remove items whose targets are no longer valid, and as such you cannot send the files if they've since been moved, renamed, deleted or existed on a drive which isn't currently available.

Comment: Thanks Compo, i'll have to do an if exist on it.

Comment: Thanks Compo. I thought it didn't function but I was wrong. It just takes some time!

Comment: The time it takes is because it uses the `Like` operator. I've found that using more filters can speed the process up somewhat, without that it is effectively running through every shortcut on your system, then performing a pattern match on every one of them. If you change the `Where` clause to the following, for example, it should perform quicker: `"Drive='%AppData:~,2%' And Path='\\Users\\%UserName%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\' And Extension='lnk'"`. Of course, were I to be performing this task, I would probably still use [tag:WMI], but through [tag:PowerShell] instead.